# How to copy Java Collections list

Tags: java, list, collections, copy

I have an `ArrayList` and I want to copy it exactly. I use utility classes when possible on the assumption that someone spent some time making it correct. So naturally, I end up with the `Collections` class which contains a copy method.

Suppose I have the following:

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
a.add("a");
a.add("b");
a.add("c");
List<String> b = new ArrayList<String>(a.size());

Collections.copy(b,a);
```

This fails because basically it thinks `b` isn't big enough to hold `a`. Yes I know `b` has size 0, but it should be big enough now shouldn't it? If I have to fill `b` first, then `Collections.copy()` becomes a completely useless function in my mind. So, except for programming a copy function (which I'm going to do now) is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: The doc for Collections.copy() says "The destination list must be at least as long as the source list.".

Comment: I don't think the accepted answer is correct

Comment: You accepted an incorrect answer, Jasper Floor. I sincerely hope you did not use the wrong information in your code!

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Calling

```
List<String> b = new ArrayList<String>(a);
```

creates a shallow copy of `a` within `b`. All elements will exist within `b` in the exact same order that they were within `a` (assuming it had an order).

Similarly, calling

```
// note: instantiating with a.size() gives `b` enough capacity to hold everything
List<String> b = new ArrayList<String>(a.size());
Collections.copy(b, a);
```

also creates a shallow copy of `a` within `b`. If the first parameter, `b`, does not have enough *capacity* (not size) to contain all of `a`'s elements, then it will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. The expectation is that no allocations will be required by [`Collections.copy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#copy%28java.util.List,%20java.util.List%29) to work, and if any are, then it throws that exception. It's an optimization to require the copied collection to be preallocated (`b`), but I generally do not think that the feature is worth it due to the required checks given the constructor-based alternatives like the one shown above that have no weird side effects.

To create a deep copy, the `List`, via either mechanism, would have to have intricate knowledge of the underlying type. In the case of `String`s, which are immutable in Java (and .NET for that matter), you don't even need a deep copy. In the case of `MySpecialObject`, you need to know how to make a deep copy of it and that is not a generic operation.

---

Note: The originally accepted answer was the top result for `Collections.copy` in Google, and it was flat out wrong as pointed out in the comments.

Comment: @ncasas Yes it does. I am lamenting the fact that there is not a generic "copy" function in Java. In practice, all to often I find that other authors have not implemented clone() for their classes; it leaves one without the ability to do any sort of copy of an object. Or, even worse, I see an implemented clone method with either no or poor documentation, which makes the clone function unusable (in a reliable and practical "knowing what's happening" sense).

Answer (score 135):

`b` has a *capacity* of 3, but a *size* of 0. The fact that `ArrayList` has some sort of buffer capacity is an implementation detail - it's not part of the `List` interface, so `Collections.copy(List, List)` doesn't use it. It would be ugly for it to special-case `ArrayList`.

As tddmonkey has indicated, using the ArrayList constructor which takes a collection is the way to in the example provided.

For more complicated scenarios (which may well include your real code), you may find the collections within [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) useful.

Answer (score 63):

Just do:

```
List a = new ArrayList(); 
a.add("a"); 
a.add("b"); 
a.add("c"); 
List b = new ArrayList(a);
```

ArrayList has a constructor that will accept another Collection to copy the elements from

Comment: as someone below comments, this is a shallow copy. Otherwise this would've been a fine answer. I suppose I should've specified that. Nevermind, I've moved on anyway.

Comment: For a list of strings, deep copy is not important since `String` objects are immutable.

Comment: This is not just a list of Strings!! Since this is raw type it can add any immutable(`String`) or mutable(`Date`) data. And when its a mutable data that you are adding to this raw list its basically a reference that you are copying to the other list.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan technically you're correct, but the OP specifically asked about a collection of strings.  For immutable objects, you don't need to do anything more than this

Answer (score 18):

The answer by Stephen Katulka (accepted answer) is wrong (the second part).
It explains that `Collections.copy(b, a);` does a deep copy, which it does not. Both, `new ArrayList(a);` and `Collections.copy(b, a);` only do a shallow copy. The difference is, that the constructor allocates new memory, and `copy(...)` does not, which makes it suitable in cases where you can reuse arrays, as it has a performance advantage there.

The Java standard API tries to discourage the use of deep copies, as it would be bad if new coders would use this on a regular basis, which may also be one of the reason why `clone()` is not public by default.

The source code for `Collections.copy(...)` can be seen on line 552 at:
http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Core/Collections-Jar-Zip-Logging-regex/java/util/Collections.java.htm

If you need a deep copy, you have to iterate over the items manually, using a for loop and clone() on each object.

Comment: Yes, I also noticed that. "The answer by Stephen Katulka (accepted answer) is wrong (the second part)."

Answer (score 13):

the simplest way to copy a List is to pass it to the constructor of the new list:

```
List<String> b = new ArrayList<>(a);
```

`b` will be a shallow copy of `a`

Looking at the source of `Collections.copy(List,List)` (I'd never seen it before) it seems to be for coping the elements index by index. using `List.set(int,E)` thus element 0 will over write element 0 in the target list etc etc. Not particularly clear from the javadocs I'd have to admit.

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<>(a);
a.add("foo");
b.add("bar");

List<String> b = new ArrayList<>(a); // shallow copy 'a'

// the following will all hold
assert a.get(0) == b.get(0);
assert a.get(1) == b.get(1);
assert a.equals(b);
assert a != b; // 'a' is not the same object as 'b'
```

Comment: why do you say 'shallow' copy? - me java noob

Comment: By 'shallow copy' he means that after the copy the objects in b are the same objects as in a, not copies of them.

Comment: The javadoc for Collections.copy() says "The destination list must be at least as long as the source list."

Comment: I guess I just mean it took me a couple of looks to see what the function actually did and I can see how the questioner got a little confused with exactly what it does

Comment: i'm not sure it matters? since String is immutable, only the references are not the same. however, even if u try to mutate an element in either list, it never mutates the same element in the other list

Comment: @Gareth : b will be a deep copy of a

Comment: @underdog no it won't, it will be a shallow copy, as the elements of the list will be the exactly the same i.e. the same references `assert a.get(0) == b.get(0)`

Answer (score 9):

```
List b = new ArrayList(a.size())
```

doesn't set the size. It sets the initial capacity (being how many elements it can fit in before it needs to resize).  A simpler way of copying in this case is:

```
List b = new ArrayList(a);
```

Answer (score 8):

As hoijui mentions. The selected answer from Stephen Katulka contains a comment about Collections.copy that is incorrect. The author probably accepted it because the first line of code was doing the copy that he wanted. The additional call to Collections.copy just copies again. (Resulting in the copy happening twice).

Here is code to prove it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
    a.add("a");
    a.add("b");
    a.add("c");
    List<String> b = new ArrayList<String>(a);

    System.out.println("There should be no output after this line.");

    // Note, b is already a shallow copy of a;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        if (a.get(i) != b.get(i)) {
            System.out.println("Oops, this was a deep copy."); // Note this is never called.
        }
    }

    // Now use Collections.copy and note that b is still just a shallow copy of a
    Collections.copy(b, a);
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        if (a.get(i) != b.get(i)) {
            System.out.println("Oops, i was wrong this was a deep copy"); // Note this is never called.
        }
    }

    // Now do a deep copy - requires you to explicitly copy each element
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        b.set(i, new String(a.get(i)));
    }

    // Now see that the elements are different in each 
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        if (a.get(i) == b.get(i)) {
            System.out.println("oops, i was wrong, a shallow copy was done."); // note this is never called.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Most answers here do not realize the problem, the user wants to have a COPY of the elements from first list to the second list, destination list elements are new objects and not reference to the elements of original list.
(means changing an element of second list should not change values for corresponding element of source list.)
For the mutable objects we cannot use ArrayList(Collection) constructor because it will simple refer to the original list element and will not copy.
You need to have a list cloner for each object when copying.

Answer (score 6):

Why dont you just use `addAll` method:

```
    List a = new ArrayList();
         a.add("1");
         a.add("abc");

    List b = b.addAll(listA);

//b will be 1, abc
```

even if you have existing items in b or you want to pend some elements after it, such as:

```
List a = new ArrayList();
     a.add("1");
     a.add("abc");

List b = new ArrayList();
     b.add("x");
     b.addAll(listA);
     b.add("Y");

//b will be x, 1, abc, Y
```

Answer (score 4):

Strings can be deep copied with

```
List<String> b = new ArrayList<String>(a);
```

because they are immutable. Every other Object not --> you need to iterate and do a copy by yourself.

Comment: This is still a shallow copy because each element of array `b` points to the same corresponding `String` object in `a`.  However, this is not important because, as you point out, `String` objects are immutable.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to copy an ArrayList, copy it by using:

```
List b = new ArrayList();
b.add("aa");
b.add("bb");

List a = new ArrayList(b);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
private List<Item> cloneItemList(final List<Item> items)
    {
        Item[] itemArray = new Item[items.size()];
        itemArray = items.toArray(itemArray);
        return Arrays.asList(itemArray);
    }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

Every other Object not --> you need to iterate and do a copy by yourself.

To avoid this implement Cloneable.

```
public class User implements Serializable, Cloneable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String user;
    private String password;
    ...

    @Override
    public Object clone() {
        Object o = null;
        try {
          o = super.clone();
        } catch(CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        }
        return o;
     }
 }
```

....

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

      List<User> userList1 = new ArrayList<User>();

      User user1 = new User();
      user1.setUser("User1");
      user1.setPassword("pass1");
      ...

      User user2 = new User();
      user2.setUser("User2");
      user2.setPassword("pass2");
      ...

      userList1 .add(user1);
      userList1 .add(user2);

      List<User> userList2 = new ArrayList<User>();


      for(User u: userList1){
          u.add((User)u.clone());
      }

      //With this you can avoid 
      /*
        for(User u: userList1){
            User tmp = new User();
            tmp.setUser(u.getUser);
            tmp.setPassword(u.getPassword);
            ...
            u.add(tmp);               
        }
       */

  }
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be "userList2.add((User)u.clone());" ?

Answer (score 1):

And if you are using google guava, the one line solution would be

```
List<String> b = Lists.newArrayList(a);
```

This creates a mutable array list instance.

Answer (score 1):

The following output illustrates results of using copy constructor and Collections.copy():

```
Copy [1, 2, 3] to [1, 2, 3] using copy constructor.

Copy [1, 2, 3] to (smaller) [4, 5]
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Source does not fit in dest
        at java.util.Collections.copy(Collections.java:556)
        at com.farenda.java.CollectionsCopy.copySourceToSmallerDest(CollectionsCopy.java:36)
        at com.farenda.java.CollectionsCopy.main(CollectionsCopy.java:14)

Copy [1, 2] to (same size) [3, 4]
source: [1, 2]
destination: [1, 2]

Copy [1, 2] to (bigger) [3, 4, 5]
source: [1, 2]
destination: [1, 2, 5]

Copy [1, 2] to (unmodifiable) [4, 5]
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList.set(Collections.java:1311)
        at java.util.Collections.copy(Collections.java:561)
        at com.farenda.java.CollectionsCopy.copyToUnmodifiableDest(CollectionsCopy.java:68)
        at com.farenda.java.CollectionsCopy.main(CollectionsCopy.java:20)
```

The source of full program is here: [Java List copy](http://farenda.com/java/java-list-copy). But the output is enough to see how java.util.Collections.copy() behaves.

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8 being null-safe, you could use the following code.

```
List<String> b = Optional.ofNullable(a)
                         .map(list -> (List<String>) new ArrayList<>(list))
                         .orElseGet(Collections::emptyList);
```

Or using a collector

```
List<String> b = Optional.ofNullable(a)
                         .map(List::stream)
                         .orElseGet(Stream::empty)
                         .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy isn't useless if you imagine the use case to copy some values into an existing collection. I.e. you want to overwrite existing elements instead of inserting.

An example: a = [1,2,3,4,5] b = [2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,] a.copy(b) = [1,2,3,4,5,3,3,3,3,4,4,4]

However I'd expect a copy method that would take additional parameters for the start index of the source and target collection, as well as a parameter for count.

See Java BUG [6350752](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6350752)

Answer (score -1):

To understand why Collections.copy() throws an IndexOutOfBoundsException although you've made the backing array of the destination list large enough (via the size() call on the sourceList), see the answer by Abhay Yadav in this related question:
[How to copy a java.util.List into another java.util.List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319732/how-to-copy-a-java-util-list-into-another-java-util-list)