# java arraylist of arraylist copy

Tags: java, arraylist, copy

I have code as follows:

```
    //Assume a has one arrayList in it
    List<List<Integer>> a1 = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(a);

    for(int i=0;i<1;i++){
        List<Integer> b1 = a1.get(i);
        b1.add(0);
    }

    System.out.println(a.toString()); //now there are 2 elements in arraylist a
```

I thought the above code make change only on `a1`. But the print out result shows that both arraylist `a1` and `a` are changed. How can I make only `a1` change without `a` changed as well.

Comment: I'm assuming that `a1.get(0)` (the first iteration) is referencing `a`, and then calling `add(0)` will add an element to `a`. The reason is that `List` is an object, and is passed around as a reference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy a java.util.List into another java.util.List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319732/how-to-copy-a-java-util-list-into-another-java-util-list)

Comment: @Ryan So is there any possible solution to make `a` unchangeable. If `a` and `a1` are `List<Integer>` instead of `List<List<Integer>>`, then the element adding of `a1` will not change the element of `a`. Why is it

Comment: @user3207822 You can use this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6536128/3232207 to copy out `a1.get(0)`, i.e.: `List<Integer> b1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(a1.get(0));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's a slight misunderstanding in how your code is structured when you refer to "making a change". The following line:

```
 List<Integer> b1 = a1.get(i);
```

Is, in other words:

```
"b1 is a List of Integers which is located in memory at the same place as the List of integers located at index i of a1".
```

So, b1 now references the List of integers at index i in a1 (which is the List at index 0 based on your loop, which would be the same list referenced by variable `a`).

When you write:

```
b1.add(0);
```

You are adding the integer `0` to the List of integers referenced by both `a` and `b1`. So, you are inherently changing what is in `a`, and in the process, changing the value of something held by `a1` as well.

I'm not sure exactly what you need when you say you need to modify `a1` and not `a` - do you need to add a new List of integers to the List? In that case, you can simply do a `a1.add(NewList)`, where NewList is a List

Answer (score 0):

Except putting this:

```
List<List<Integer>> a1 = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(a);
```

Do this instead:

```
a1.addAll(a);
```

So have:

```
List a = new ArrayList();
a.add("Hello");
a.add("World"); 
List a1 = new ArrayList();
a1.addAll(a);
a1.add("GoodBye");
System.out.println(a.toString());
```