# Replace class with derived class using Java annotations

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, reflection, annotations

Say I extend a Java class like `java.util.List` to create a custom class called `MyList`... Is there any way if my peers write code using `List`, I can convert it into `MyList` during compilation/runtime?

i.e. If they have something like:

```
List groceryList = new List();
```

it should be compiled/run like:

```
MyList groceryList = new MyList();
```

I know annotations can do something of this sort. Is it possible to use them in this case? If yes, how?

Comment: Why don't you just copy all the stuff from `List` to a new `MyList`?

Comment: @Sweeper: I don't want to modify code written by others. MyList is not going to change List in any functional way. Except that it has some additional convenience tweaks.

Comment: Well as is in my answer, you dont have to modify their code, just use their lists to create new MyLists in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as [downcasting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380813/downcasting-in-java).

The short answer is that if they created the object with the `new` command, such as in your example, then no, you will not be able to cast it.

What you can do, is define a constructor in `MyList` class that accepts the object-to-be-converted as a parameter and uses it to create a new object. The list is a bit special because you can [create new lists from existing ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319732/how-to-copy-a-java-util-list-into-another-java-util-list) . For example:

```
public MyList (List oldList)
{
    super(oldList); //this will copy the objects of the list to your custom list
    //But you could do any other operations to create the new object from the parameter(s)
    ...
}
```

and use it as

```
MyList groceryList = new MyList(oldList);
```

Comment: But this will mean that I've to use MyList everywhere. What I want is if my peers use List, I want it to be compiled as MyList. I have done certain enhancements in MyList which my peers aren't going to use directly. But I'd like their code to be compiled as such. Downcasting doesn't satisfy that need.

Comment: But there would be compile errors from the enhancements or new methods since the compiler does not recognize them. But I think I got the idea.. I'm not aware of a compiler capable of this. You would somehow like to annotate the List objects to be MyLists..

Comment: And also you would not have to use MyLists everywhere, since you can save a MyList to a List variable.

Comment: But what if I don't want any List objects in the bytecode at all? I want only MyList objects in the end result. The example I gave here is with List. In real usage it could be any custom class which I may not want to expose to others.

Comment: Then we will have to wait for someone smarter than me to answer :)

Comment: I don't know if what I'm asking is possible even. But thanks to you, I learned about downcasting. :) I didn't know it existed before.

Answer (score 0):

While upcasting in java is mostly safe, [Downcasting in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380813/downcasting-in-java?s=1|3.1706) is not something you should frequently use, unless really needed, since the subclass may not support some attributes or methods that the superclass can.