# Copying a basic list<string>

Tags: java

You will have to forgive me for asking this but I can't seem to find the exact answer to my question. I need to know how to copy this list:

```
List<String> jpmcRouting
```

into a new List (the name doesn't matter).

I have found answers on copying an ArrayList but not a standard list. I've tried a lot of solutions but nothing seems to work. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: You know that a 'standard' List is an interface right? That it cannot be instantiated

Comment: What kind of `List` are you trying to copy? Do you want the result to have the same class as the original?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy a java.util.List into another java.util.List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319732/how-to-copy-a-java-util-list-into-another-java-util-list)

Comment: RAnders00 this is not a duplicate. I saw that answer and did not understand it.. The list has <SomeBean> which makes no sense to me what kind of list that is and I tired the method of replacing <SomeBean> with <String> and it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<String> myCopy = new ArrayList<String>(jpmcRouting);
```

does the job.  `Collections.copy` is *not* what you want; that *only* works if the destination list *already has the right number of elements.*

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way for me is:

```
List<String> copy = jpmcRouting.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

if your result doesnt depend on order of elements in list, you can use

```
List<String> copy = jpmcRouting.parallelStream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

it will work mutch faster, but it can change order of elements

Comment: Using a parallel stream means that it may be done using parallelism. It won't change the order of the elements in the answer.

Comment: I got an index out of bounds for this.

Comment: are you sure? this is really safe... All methods are internal java methods.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I think `Collections.copy(b, a);` will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
List<String> b = new ArrayList<String>(jpmcRouting.size());
Collections.copy(b, jpmcRouting);
```

Comment: Thanks that's what I was looking for, I'll accept in 5 minutes.

Comment: This will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` at runtime unless the original list is empty, meaning it will basically never work.

Comment: Yes Louis is correct, I got an error. 

Any suggestion on how to fix this?