# Java 8 streams how to filter contents a List not found in another arrayList?

Tags: java, java-8

Can I filter an array list based on the elements found in another array list in java 8? The whole story is that I have fetched list of active employees from oracle E-business suite app

```
**EmpID**
00123
003456
023299
```

and I have a separate file which contains photo with file Name **EmpID.jpeg**

```
**FileName**
00123.jpeg
003456.jpeg
023299.jpeg
```

Now my purpose is to compare the lists and to filter employees who provide me photos and from those they did not give me.

```
private ArrayList<String> _IDsFromFile;
private ArrayList<String> _IDsFromImage;

      ---
      ---

public void compareAndCopy(String fileName){

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy a java.util.List into another java.util.List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319732/how-to-copy-a-java-util-list-into-another-java-util-list)

Comment: Is there ever a case in which you'll anticipate duplicates in these collections?  That is, will you ever have another employee with ID "00123" or have potentially *two* images called "00123.jpeg"?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First of all, you should convert one or the other of these lists into a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), so that the [`.contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) check is efficient. Calling `.contains()` on a `List` is a linear-time operation, meaning doing so *n* times is quadratic.

Once you've done that it's straightforward to use [`.filter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) or even [`.partitioningBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy-java.util.function.Predicate-) to determine where the two lists overlap.

```
Set<String> imageIdsSet = new HashSet<>(IDsFromImage);

List<String> overlappingIds = IDsFromFile.stream()
    .filter(imageIdsSet::contains)
    .collect(toList());

// OR

Map<Boolean, List<String>> partitionedIds = IDsFromFile.stream()
    .collect(partitioningBy(imageIdsSet::contains));
List<String> overlappingIds = partitionedIds.get(true);
List<String> missingIds = partitionedIds.get(false);
```

---

What you're describing, in principle, are [set operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)#Basic_operations). The "overlapping" IDs are the *intersection* of the two sets of IDs, while the "missing" IDs are the *difference*.

[Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) provides efficient implementations of these operations in their [`Sets`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html) utility. ([`union`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#union-java.util.Set-java.util.Set-), [`intersection`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#intersection-java.util.Set-java.util.Set-), [`difference`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#difference-java.util.Set-java.util.Set-), and [`complementOf`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#complementOf-java.util.Collection-)).

Answer (score 7):

You can use [filter API in java 8 Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) to do it. Like the following code snippet:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

/**
 * @author Shizhz
 */
public class Main {
    private static Set<String> _IDsFromFile;
    private static Set<String> _IDsFromImage;

    static {
        _IDsFromFile = new HashSet();
        _IDsFromFile.add("00123");
        _IDsFromFile.add("003456");
        _IDsFromFile.add("023299");
        _IDsFromFile.add("023300");

        _IDsFromImage = new HashSet<>();
        _IDsFromImage.add("00123.jpeg");
        _IDsFromImage.add("003456.jpeg");
        _IDsFromImage.add("023299.jpeg");
    }

    private static Set<String> filterEmployeesWithPhones(Set<String> employeeSet, Set<String> photoSet) {
        return employeeSet.stream().filter(empId -> photoSet.contains(empId + ".jpeg")).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        filterEmployeesWithPhones(_IDsFromFile, _IDsFromImage).forEach(emp -> System.out.println(emp));
    }
}
```

will give you the result:

> 00123
>
> 003456
>
> 023299

Comment: This is more or less correct, but not performant due to the O(n) time for a list to determine element membership.  If you could use `Set`s instead, then it'd be crazy good.

Comment: @Makoto, yes you're right, updated my code snippet. And I think `Set` is ok  for both `employee` and `phone` collection in this case. Thanks for you suggestion :-)

Comment: Thank you that is a great solution. ya set will perform good. esp with large number of employees