# Trying to find set of all permutations of an integer array elements

Tags: java, algorithm

Variable 'result' is blank when printed inside main method.
Can someone guide me how to structure the code? New to java. apologies if the Q is naive.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class StringPermutation {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] a = new int[]{1,2,3};
        System.out.println(permute(a)); 
    }

    public static List<List<Integer>> permute(int[] a) {        
        List<Integer> path = new ArrayList<>();
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList(path);
        boolean[] visited = new boolean[a.length];
        helper(result, path, visited, a);
        //System.out.println(result);
        return result;
    }

    private static void helper(List<List<Integer>> result, List<Integer> path, boolean[] visited, int[] a) {
        if (path.size() == a.length)
            result.add(path);           

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (visited[i]) continue;
            path.add(a[i]);
            visited[i] = true;
            helper(result, path, visited, a );
            path.remove(path.size() - 1);
            visited[i] = false;                     
        }                       
    }
}
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843506 i.e. `result.add(path)` does not copy `path`.

Comment: `List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList(path)` doesn't do what you (probably) think it does, and also gives a warning about using raw types.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of some combination of [Why does my ArrayList contain N copies of the last item added to the list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19843506) and [How to copy a java.util.List into another java.util.List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14319732)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the reference to `path` list in every recursion call.

When the recursion condition was `true` you have to clone the `path` list or add a new List passing the current `path` list:

```
//This constructor will create a new List adding the elements of `path`.
result.add(new ArrayList<>(path));
```

---

```
public class StringPermutation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = new int[]{1, 2, 3};
        System.out.println(permute(a));
    }

    public static List<List<Integer>> permute(int[] a) {
        List<Integer> path = new ArrayList<>();
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean[] visited = new boolean[a.length];
        helper(result, path, visited, a);
        //System.out.println(result);
        return result;
    }

    private static void helper(List<List<Integer>> result, List<Integer> path, boolean[] visited, int[] a) {
        if (path.size() == a.length)
            result.add(new ArrayList<>(path));

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (visited[i]) continue;
            path.add(a[i]);
            visited[i] = true;
            helper(result, path, visited, a);
            path.remove(path.size() - 1);
            visited[i] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**After call the main program, the output will be:**

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```