# Why Copied ArrayList gets modified when I am modifying the original ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

```
ArrayList<Integer> aList1=new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> aList2=new ArrayList<Integer>();
aList1.add(1);
aList2=aList1;
aList1.clear();

System.out.println(aList1.size());
System.out.println(aList2.size());
```

Why here both lists have size zero? As per my understanding `aList1.size()` should be `0` and `aList2.size()` should be `1`.

Comment: Read this post and it's answers... This will clear things up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: See also: [How to copy a java.util.List into another java.util.List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319732/how-to-copy-a-java-util-list-into-another-java-util-list)

Answer (score 2):

When you make an assign like this :

```
aList2 = aList1;
```

The `aList2` will point to the same Memory address of `aList1` for that when you change `aList1` the first also changed.

---

Consider you have a list like this :

```
      +---+     +---+
O---> | 1 | --- | 2 |
      +---+     +---+
```

When you assign :

```
aList2 = aList1;
```

It will be like this :

```
                  +---+     +---+
      +--> L1---> | 1 | --- | 2 |
      |           +---+     +---+
      |
  L2--+
```

When you change L1 the

```
  aList1.clear();
```

the other list also will be affected

```
      +--> L1---> null
      |           
      |
  L2--+
```

---

to solve this issue you can use :

```
aList2 = new ArrayList<>(aList1);
```

This will return :

```
0
1
```

Comment: I know how to solve the issue, I wanted to know the reason.

Comment: I already said the reason @008ak89 did you read my answer?

Comment: So why it is different for any class,Parent p1=new Parent();
  Parent p2=p1;
  
  p1=null;
  
  System.out.println(p1);
  System.out.println(p2);

Comment: @008ak89 what did you mean I don't get you?

Comment: "The aList2 will point to the same Memory address of aList1" i.e. both the objects will be pointing to the same memory address, then why in this example p1 is null but p2 is having some reference. Parent p1=new Parent(); Parent p2=p1; p1=null; System.out.println(p1); System.out.println(p2);

Comment: @008ak89 please read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177247/discussion-between-008ak89-and-ycf-l).