# What would happen if I did this while trying to change a list's contents?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a list be a direct copy of another. Would this work?

```
list1 = list2
```

Would it transfer all contents or nothing at all?

Comment: It will not copy the object you're just assign a reference to a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not making a copy, you are adding a reference. Both making an additional reference and inserting items into a list are *atomic*. A procedure is atomic if it is not splittable. Either it is completely done or not.

See also the following thread on how to correctly clone a list.
[Java Collections copy list - I don't understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689370/java-collections-copy-list-i-dont-understand)

Googling for the `java clone method` will enlighten you too.

Answer (score 0):

It won't. Cloning objects in java is not so stright forward, see the link [How do I copy an object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869033/how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

No. It will only make `list2` reference point to the same list that is stored in `list1` reference. You can use `copy constructor` to copy references from one list to another, but be careful since this is not deep copy -> new list will contain exactly the same objects that are stored in original list. Here is example

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add("one");
list1.add("two");

List<String> list2 = list1;//now list2 will point to the same list as list1
list2.add("A");

//lets print content of list1
System.out.println(list1); // -> output: [one, two, A]

//--------------------------------------------------------------

//This way you can create separate list that contains same values as list1
List<String> list3 = new ArrayList(list1);
list3.add("B");

System.out.println(list1); // -> output: [one, two, A]
System.out.println(list3); // -> output: [one, two, A, B]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a direct assignment is not useful in most cases. It just as if you have the **exact** same variable with two different names as both pointing to *the same* memory address.

If you want to clone a list into another you should use a `copy constructor`

e.g.

```
ArrayList<E> copyList = new ArrayList<E>(originalList);
```