# Using HashMaps Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm writing a method that allows me to count how many times an element of type String shows up in a LinkedList of type Strings. my code shown below does not work. I keep getting index out of bounds in the line i commented on down below. Can't seem to find the bug

```
public int findDuplicate (LinkedList<String> e) {
int j = 1;
LinkedList<String> test = e;
while (!test.isEmpty()){
    test = e;
    String value = test.pop();
    //Screws up here when i = 6 
    for(int i =0; i<=test.size() && test.get(i)!=null; i++){ 
        String value3 = test.get(i);
        if(e.get(i).equals(value) && i<=test.size()){
            String value2 = test.get(i); 
            j++;
            String Duplicate = e.get(i);
            e.remove(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(value + " is listed " + j + " times");

}
return j;
}
```

using hashmaps.. still doesn't work

```
public void findDuplicate (LinkedList e) {

    Map<String,Integer> counts = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

    while(!e.isEmpty()){
        String value = e.pop();
        for(int i =0; i<e.size(); i++){
            counts.put(value, i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(counts.toString());
}
```

My code should go through the linked list find out how many times an element within the list appears and deletes duplicates from the list at the same time. Then prints the element and the number of times it appears in the list. I posted about this last night but didn't get a response yet. Sorry for the repost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your hashmap example to count the duplicates:

```
@Test
public void countOccurrences() {
    LinkedList<String> strings = new LinkedList<String>(){{
        add("Fred");
        add("Fred");
        add("Joe");
        add("Mary");
        add("Mary");
        add("Mary");
    }};

    Map<String,Integer> count = count(strings,new HashMap<String,Integer>());
    System.out.println("count = " + count);
}

private Map<String, Integer> count(List<String> strings, Map<String, Integer> runningCount) {
    if(strings.isEmpty()) {
        return runningCount;
    }
    String current = strings.get(0);
    int startingSize = strings.size();
    while(strings.contains(current)) {
        strings.remove(current);
    }
    runningCount.put(current, startingSize - strings.size());
    return count(strings,runningCount);
}
```

If you want the original strings list preserved you could do

```
    Map<String,Integer> count = count(new LinkedList<String>(strings),new HashMap<String,Integer>());
    System.out.println("strings = " + strings);
    System.out.println("count = " + count);
```

Answer (score 6):

You are running off the end of the list.  Change

```
for(int i =0; i<=test.size() && test.get(i)!=null; i++){
```

to

```
for(int i =0; i< test.size() && test.get(i)!=null; i++){
```

Valid indexes for a `List` (or an array) are `0` through `size() - 1`.

Answer (score 2):

Check out google's guava collections which has a perfect class for maintaining a map and getting a count:

https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#BiMap

```
Multiset<String> wordsMultiset = HashMultiset.create();
wordsMultiset.addAll(words);
// now we can use wordsMultiset.count(String) to find the count of a word
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't affect your out of bounds issue, but you are removing elements from your list while still evaluating it. If you remove an element, you should call `i--` afterwards, or you skip the next entity (which is re-indexed) for evaluation.

Also of note regarding your code, I see you are trying to make a copy of your list, but standard assignment means `test` and `e` both point to the same instance.  You need to use `Collections.copy()` see [this SO thread on how to use the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689370/java-collections-copy-list-i-dont-understand).

Answer (score 1):

I hope you realize what the `test = e` statement is doing. After this statement executes both `test` and `e` refer to the **same** object.

If anyone of them modifies the list, the other sees it as they both are looking at the same object.

If this is not intended you need to *clone* the list before assigning it to another list reference.