# How to "propagate" the sorting of an `ArrayList<String>` to another one?

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

I have multiple `ArrayList<String>`s "linked" into a custom adapter I'm using to build a list view.
Now suppose they are just two in total, to simplify.
I want to sort one of them and then have this new order reflected into the other one, in order to maintain the list consistent.

This is what I was thinking to do and doesn't work, ending with an `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0` at the line signed with `*`.

```
// initial declarations:
List<String> filenameEntries = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> idEntries = new ArrayList<String>();

/* various operations that fill
the two ArrayList here... */

// sorting:
List<String> oldFilenameEntries = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> oldIdEntries = new ArrayList<String>();

oldFilenameEntries = filenameEntries;
oldIdEntries = idEntries;

idEntries.clear();

Collections.sort(filenameEntries);

for (int i = 0; i < filenameEntries.size(); i++ ) {
    for (int j = 0; j < oldFilenameEntries.size(); j++ ) {
        if (oldFilenameEntries.get(j) == filenameEntries.get(i)) {
            idEntries.add(oldIdEntries.get(j));  // *
        }
    }
}
```

My idea was to search into the old ArrayList for every element from the new one, and then use this "old" index to re-polulate the other ArrayList.

(I have the restriction that the other "sorted" ArrayList must be again `idEntries`. This is way I did this sort of transfer)

Any suggestion?
Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I thought it was a sorting issue and then came out I missed the right way to make a copy for the ArrayLists. Thanks to everyone that pointed out that the error was at

```
oldFilenameEntries = filenameEntries;
oldIdEntries = idEntries;
```

and why.

I accepted the answer that pointed me more quickly to the solution.
I removed the two lines above and changed the previous into

```
List<String> oldFilenameEntries = new ArrayList<String>(filenameEntries);
List<String> oldIdEntries = new ArrayList<String>(idEntries);
```

and from what I can see ATM all seems to work as expected.

Comment: 'I want to sort one of them...' How do you sort this one list? You could simply apply this 'sorting' to the other list(s).

Comment: @mike: with *Collections.sort(filenameEntries);*. Then this new oder has to be reflected to the other ArrayList(s).

Comment: So why you don't just sort the others with the same sorting mechanism? It would be straight forward. Or write a comparator, if you want more sophisticated sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in these 2 lines:

```
oldFilenameEntries = filenameEntries;
oldIdEntries = idEntries;
```

After this, both `old...` and original variables point to the same list. Then you call `idEntries.clear()`. This clears both `idEntries` and `oldIdEntries` since they point to the same list.

For this to work, you need to copy the list instead of just assigning it. You could use `Collections.copy()`. Here is an example:

[Java Collections copy list - I don't understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689370/java-collections-copy-list-i-dont-understand)

On a different note, this approach seems too complex - but it's also not very clear what you are trying to accomplish so I can't suggest a better way.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is the assignment: `oldIdEntries = idEntries;` this is causing both references to point to same list so when you do `idEntries.clear();` you have cleared the one list to which both are pointing. You need to make a copy of the list not just assign the reference.

[Collections.copy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#copy%28java.util.List,%20java.util.List%29)

[Lists.copy](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#newArrayList%28java.lang.Iterable%29)

[ImmutableList.copy()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html#copyOf%28java.lang.Iterable%29)

Comment: I marked the answer as useful. Thanks for the pointers to the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the soreted list, clone each object and then add it to the new array list

Answer (score 0):

**Two issues:
One:**

```
oldFilenameEntries = filenameEntries;
oldIdEntries = idEntries;
```

Now, both old and new entries point to the same list. 
Then, `idEntries.clear().`
This clears both old and new entries.
If you want to do this *somehow*, use `Collections.copy()`

**Two:**
If you're just going to check for equality, I don't see why you need to have two for-loops, and have both sorted.

You could just do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < filenameEntries.size(); i++ ) {
        if (oldFilenameEntries.contains(filenameEntries.get(i)) {
            idEntries.add(oldIdEntries.get(j));  // *
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: as I don't know what the original point of your code was, and equality checking was all I could infer from your snippet, I'm suggesting this.