# Adding one list items to another list

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections

I have to add the items of one list to another, what is the preferred way and why ?

```
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList();
list1.add(1);
list1.add(2);
list1.add(3);
```

**Method #1:**

```
List<Integer> list2 = list1;
```

**Method #2:**

```
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList();   
list2.addAll(list1)
```

AFAIK that in first method list1's reference will be assigned to list2 so any modification to list1 will effect to list2, Am i correct ?

Is there any side effect of using first over second or vice-versa ?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

I have seen the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689370/how-to-copy-java-collections-list):, I just wanted to know how both of the above approaches are different and what's the trade off using one above other ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy Java Collections list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689370/how-to-copy-java-collections-list)

Comment: Yes, as for first method, both `list1` and `list2` will refer to the same data, so any modification will affect another. BTW, the better way for second method is: List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>(list1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write

```
List<Integer> list2 = list1;
```

... you are making `list2` point to `list1`. If `list1` is changed, `list2` will change as well. If it's disposed, also `list2` will be disposed.

For example:

```
list2 = list1;
list1.remove(3); //<-- list2 will also reflect remove(3)
list1.add(4); //<-- list2 will also get a 4 at the end of the list
```

If you use

```
list2.addAll(list1);
//or list2 = new ArrayList<>(list1);
```

... then you are creating a new list, independent from the first one, that contains a copy of the elements (in the same order) than `list1` at the moment in which you are initializing it.
The two lists will be completely independent in their structure.

```
list2.addAll(list1);
list1.remove(3); //<-- list 2 is unchanged
list1.add(4); //<-- list 2 is unchanged
```

Note that if `list2` contains objects and one of the object changes, it will change both in `list1` and `list2` (because the list contains the references to the objects, not the values).

This said, the right way depends on what you want to do.
If you want to reference `list1` into another object and want it to be the mirror of `list1`, then go for method 1.
But most probably, you just want a copy of your `list1` at a given instant, so in that case, you should use `list2`.

Answer (score 0):

1. `list2` will become just a reference to `list1`. Any changes on any of them will be applied to both (in fact both is just a reference to same list).
2. After this you will have access to both `list1` and `list2` and both will have different references, what means that changes on one, won't affect another.

Answer (score 0):

> AFAIK that in first method list1's reference will be assigned to list2 so any modification to list1 will effect to list2, Am i correct ?

Yes, you are correct. `List<Integer> list2 = list1;` means that you have multiple variables pointing to the same `List`. If you change the content of one, this also changes the content of the other list.

> Is there any side effect of using first over second or vice-versa ?

When using the second methods, you will have multiple independent lists containing the same elements. If you then add/remove items (or similar), the change won't be reflected to the other `List`.

In fact, you can even pass a `Collection` to the constructor of `ArrayList` doing the same thing:

```java
List<Integer> list2=new ArrayList<>(list2);
```